# One nginx process with two gunicorn services on the same VM -> gunicorn returns "Not Found" errors

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, flask, gunicorn

I have two small, low-volume, Flask-based web services, which I thought I could serve up via one nginx instance, to save VMs.  I apologize for asking, as I have seen similar questions here, but haven't yet succeeded in getting it to work.

Both small services work fine with nginx/gunicorn individually, but I cannot get them to work if they are both specified in the nginx config.
Tracing the debug log, it seems gunicorn always returns 'Not found' errors.  The smallest trivial case I can build to demonstrate is the following:

Both "services" "myproject" and "yourproject" are identical except for the name:

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/yourproject")
def hello():
    return "<h1 style='color:red'>Hello There from YourProject!</h1>"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0')
```

The services are both defined similarly, only showing one:

```
[Unit]
Description=Gunicorn instance to serve yourproject
After=network.target

[Service]
User=myuserid
Group=www-data
WorkingDirectory=/home/myuserid/yourproject
Environment="PATH=/home/myuserid/yourproject/yourprojectenv/bin"
ExecStart=/home/myuserid/yourproject/yourprojectenv/bin/gunicorn --workers 3 --bind unix:yourproject.sock -m 007 wsgi:app

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Both services work fine when run with gunicorn (on port 5000), and when run with nginx+gunicorn, if the service is run alone.

I tried a number of variants of the following nginx specification, but none works:

```
error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log debug;

server {

    listen 80 default_server;
    server_name <myIP>;

    location = /favicon.ico {access_log off;log_not_found off;}

    location ~ myproject {
        include proxy_params;
        proxy_pass http://unix:/home/myuserid/myproject/myproject.sock;
    }

    location ~ yourproject {
        include proxy_params;
        proxy_pass http://unix:/home/myuserid/yourproject/yourproject.sock;
    }
}
```

(The included proxy_params is the standard nginx file.)

I restart nginx and test this from a browser on the same box:

```
http://<myIP>/yourproject
```

and get "Not Found".

This --long, sorry-- snippet from the nginx error.log may show what is going wrong, though I am too ignorant to see it myself:

```
2021/08/31 13:41:14 [debug] 11982#11982: accept on 0.0.0.0:80, ready: 0
2021/08/31 13:41:14 [debug] 11982#11982: posix_memalign: 0000560E0FE5E630:512 @16
2021/08/31 13:41:14 [debug] 11982#11982: *6 accept: 131.130.118.77:58306 fd:20
2021/08/31 13:41:14 [debug] 11982#11982: *6 event timer add: 20: 60000:6357742
2021/08/31 13:41:14 [debug] 11982#11982: *6 reusable connection: 1
2021/08/31 13:41:14 [debug] 11982#11982: *6 epoll add event: fd:20 op:1 ev:80002001
2021/08/31 13:41:14 [debug] 11982#11982: accept on 0.0.0.0:80, ready: 0
2021/08/31 13:41:14 [debug] 11982#11982: posix_memalign: 0000560E0FE43D10:512 @16
2021/08/31 13:41:14 [debug] 11982#11982: *7 accept: 131.130.118.77:58308 fd:21
2021/08/31 13:41:14 [debug] 11982#11982: *7 event timer add: 21: 60000:6357742
2021/08/31 13:41:14 [debug] 11982#11982: *7 reusable connection: 1
2021/08/31 13:41:14 [debug] 11982#11982: *7 epoll add event: fd:21 op:1 ev:80002001
2021/08/31 13:41:14 [debug] 11982#11982: *6 http wait request handler
2021/08/31 13:41:14 [debug] 11982#11982: *6 malloc: 0000560E0FE44720:1024
2021/08/31 13:41:14 [debug] 11982#11982: *6 recv: eof:0, avail:-1
2021/08/31 13:41:14 [debug] 11982#11982: *6 recv: fd:20 434 of 1024
2021/08/31 13:41:14 [debug] 11982#11982: *6 reusable connection: 0
2021/08/31 13:41:14 [debug] 11982#11982: *6 posix_memalign: 0000560E0FE8F3B0:4096 @16
2021/08/31 13:41:14 [debug] 11982#11982: *6 http process request line
2021/08/31 13:41:14 [debug] 11982#11982: *6 http request line: "GET /yourproject HTTP/1.1"
2021/08/31 13:41:14 [debug] 11982#11982: *6 http uri: "/yourproject"
2021/08/31 13:41:14 [debug] 11982#11982: *6 http args: ""
2021/08/31 13:41:14 [debug] 11982#11982: *6 http exten: ""
2021/08/31 13:41:14 [debug] 11982#11982: *6 posix_memalign: 0000560E0FE643A0:4096 @16
2021/08/31 13:41:14 [debug] 11982#11982: *6 http process request header line
2021/08/31 13:41:14 [debug] 11982#11982: *6 http header: "Host: <myIP>"
2021/08/31 13:41:14 [debug] 11982#11982: *6 http header: "Connection: keep-alive"
2021/08/31 13:41:14 [debug] 11982#11982: *6 http header: "Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1"
2021/08/31 13:41:14 [debug] 11982#11982: *6 http header: "User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/92.0.4515.159 Safari/537.36"
2021/08/31 13:41:14 [debug] 11982#11982: *6 http header: "Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9"
2021/08/31 13:41:14 [debug] 11982#11982: *6 http header: "Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate"
2021/08/31 13:41:14 [debug] 11982#11982: *6 http header: "Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9"
2021/08/31 13:41:14 [debug] 11982#11982: *6 http header done
2021/08/31 13:41:14 [debug] 11982#11982: *6 event timer del: 20: 6357742
2021/08/31 13:41:14 [debug] 11982#11982: *6 generic phase: 0
2021/08/31 13:41:14 [debug] 11982#11982: *6 rewrite phase: 1
2021/08/31 13:41:14 [debug] 11982#11982: *6 test location: "/favicon.ico"
2021/08/31 13:41:14 [debug] 11982#11982: *6 test location: ~ "myproject"
2021/08/31 13:41:14 [debug] 11982#11982: *6 test location: ~ "yourproject"
2021/08/31 13:41:14 [debug] 11982#11982: *6 using configuration "yourproject"
2021/08/31 13:41:14 [debug] 11982#11982: *6 http cl:-1 max:1048576
2021/08/31 13:41:14 [debug] 11982#11982: *6 rewrite phase: 3
2021/08/31 13:41:14 [debug] 11982#11982: *6 post rewrite phase: 4
2021/08/31 13:41:14 [debug] 11982#11982: *6 generic phase: 5
2021/08/31 13:41:14 [debug] 11982#11982: *6 generic phase: 6
2021/08/31 13:41:14 [debug] 11982#11982: *6 generic phase: 7
2021/08/31 13:41:14 [debug] 11982#11982: *6 access phase: 8
2021/08/31 13:41:14 [debug] 11982#11982: *6 access phase: 9
2021/08/31 13:41:14 [debug] 11982#11982: *6 access phase: 10
2021/08/31 13:41:14 [debug] 11982#11982: *6 post access phase: 11
2021/08/31 13:41:14 [debug] 11982#11982: *6 generic phase: 12
2021/08/31 13:41:14 [debug] 11982#11982: *6 generic phase: 13
2021/08/31 13:41:14 [debug] 11982#11982: *6 http init upstream, client timer: 0
2021/08/31 13:41:14 [debug] 11982#11982: *6 epoll add event: fd:20 op:3 ev:80002005
2021/08/31 13:41:14 [debug] 11982#11982: *6 http script copy: "Host"
2021/08/31 13:41:14 [debug] 11982#11982: *6 http script var: "<myIP>"
2021/08/31 13:41:14 [debug] 11982#11982: *6 http script copy: "X-Real-IP"
2021/08/31 13:41:14 [debug] 11982#11982: *6 http script var: "<myIP>"
2021/08/31 13:41:14 [debug] 11982#11982: *6 http script copy: "X-Forwarded-For"
2021/08/31 13:41:14 [debug] 11982#11982: *6 http script var: "<myIP>"
2021/08/31 13:41:14 [debug] 11982#11982: *6 http script copy: "X-Forwarded-Proto"
2021/08/31 13:41:14 [debug] 11982#11982: *6 http script var: "http"
2021/08/31 13:41:14 [debug] 11982#11982: *6 http script copy: "Connection"
2021/08/31 13:41:14 [debug] 11982#11982: *6 http script copy: "close"
2021/08/31 13:41:14 [debug] 11982#11982: *6 http script copy: ""
2021/08/31 13:41:14 [debug] 11982#11982: *6 http script copy: ""
2021/08/31 13:41:14 [debug] 11982#11982: *6 http proxy header: "Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1"
2021/08/31 13:41:14 [debug] 11982#11982: *6 http proxy header: "User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/92.0.4515.159 Safari/537.36"
2021/08/31 13:41:14 [debug] 11982#11982: *6 http proxy header: "Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9"
2021/08/31 13:41:14 [debug] 11982#11982: *6 http proxy header: "Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate"
2021/08/31 13:41:14 [debug] 11982#11982: *6 http proxy header: "Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9"
2021/08/31 13:41:14 [debug] 11982#11982: *6 http proxy header:
"GET /yourproject HTTP/1.0
Host: <myIP>
X-Real-IP: <myIP>
X-Forwarded-For: <myIP>
X-Forwarded-Proto: http
Connection: close
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/92.0.4515.159 Safari/537.36
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9

"
2021/08/31 13:41:14 [debug] 11982#11982: *6 http cleanup add: 0000560E0FE64EC0
2021/08/31 13:41:14 [debug] 11982#11982: *6 get rr peer, try: 1
2021/08/31 13:41:14 [debug] 11982#11982: *6 stream socket 22
2021/08/31 13:41:14 [debug] 11982#11982: *6 epoll add connection: fd:22 ev:80002005
2021/08/31 13:41:14 [debug] 11982#11982: *6 connect to unix:/home/myuserid/yourproject/yourproject.sock, fd:22 #8
2021/08/31 13:41:14 [debug] 11982#11982: *6 connected
2021/08/31 13:41:14 [debug] 11982#11982: *6 http upstream connect: 0
2021/08/31 13:41:14 [debug] 11982#11982: *6 posix_memalign: 0000560E0FE3E6C0:128 @16
2021/08/31 13:41:14 [debug] 11982#11982: *6 http upstream send request
2021/08/31 13:41:14 [debug] 11982#11982: *6 http upstream send request body
2021/08/31 13:41:14 [debug] 11982#11982: *6 chain writer buf fl:1 s:514
2021/08/31 13:41:14 [debug] 11982#11982: *6 chain writer in: 0000560E0FE64F00
2021/08/31 13:41:14 [debug] 11982#11982: *6 writev: 514 of 514
2021/08/31 13:41:14 [debug] 11982#11982: *6 chain writer out: 0000000000000000
2021/08/31 13:41:14 [debug] 11982#11982: *6 event timer add: 22: 60000:6357746
2021/08/31 13:41:14 [debug] 11982#11982: *6 http finalize request: -4, "/yourproject?" a:1, c:2
2021/08/31 13:41:14 [debug] 11982#11982: *6 http request count:2 blk:0
2021/08/31 13:41:14 [debug] 11982#11982: *6 http run request: "/yourproject?"
2021/08/31 13:41:14 [debug] 11982#11982: *6 http upstream check client, write event:1, "/yourproject"
2021/08/31 13:41:14 [debug] 11982#11982: *6 http upstream request: "/yourproject?"
2021/08/31 13:41:14 [debug] 11982#11982: *6 http upstream dummy handler
2021/08/31 13:41:14 [debug] 11982#11982: *6 http upstream request: "/yourproject?"
2021/08/31 13:41:14 [debug] 11982#11982: *6 http upstream dummy handler
2021/08/31 13:41:14 [debug] 11982#11982: *6 http upstream request: "/yourproject?"
2021/08/31 13:41:14 [debug] 11982#11982: *6 http upstream process header
2021/08/31 13:41:14 [debug] 11982#11982: *6 malloc: 0000560E0FE653B0:4096
2021/08/31 13:41:14 [debug] 11982#11982: *6 recv: eof:0, avail:-1
2021/08/31 13:41:14 [debug] 11982#11982: *6 recv: fd:22 393 of 4096
2021/08/31 13:41:14 [debug] 11982#11982: *6 http proxy status 404 "404 NOT FOUND"
2021/08/31 13:41:14 [debug] 11982#11982: *6 http proxy header: "Server: gunicorn"
2021/08/31 13:41:14 [debug] 11982#11982: *6 http proxy header: "Date: Tue, 31 Aug 2021 11:41:14 GMT"
2021/08/31 13:41:14 [debug] 11982#11982: *6 http proxy header: "Connection: close"
2021/08/31 13:41:14 [debug] 11982#11982: *6 http proxy header: "Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8"
2021/08/31 13:41:14 [debug] 11982#11982: *6 http proxy header: "Content-Length: 232"
2021/08/31 13:41:14 [debug] 11982#11982: *6 http proxy header done
2021/08/31 13:41:14 [debug] 11982#11982: *6 xslt filter header
2021/08/31 13:41:14 [debug] 11982#11982: *6 posix_memalign: 0000560E0FE663C0:4096 @16
2021/08/31 13:41:14 [debug] 11982#11982: *6 HTTP/1.1 404 NOT FOUND
(... some more formatting of the reponse...)
```

I would appreciate any pointers or assistance on this, it is driving me nuts.